# jax-rs & mvc: return view as string issue

Tags: intellij-idea, model-view-controller, jax-rs, glassfish-4

I'm using `javax.ws.rs-api` and `javax.mvc` maven libraries to build an mvc restful web based app.
but i cant return view.the `preAdd` method return view just as  a simple string. it does'nt return actual view.
my webserver is glassfish4

```
@Path("/home")
public class HomeController {

    @Controller
    @Path("new")
    @GET
    public String preAdd() {
        return "/WEB-INF/jsp/edit.jsp"; // it echo the exact string on the screen: "/WEB-INF/jsp/edit.jsp"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Glassfish 5. Glassfish 4 still uses EE 7. Maybe that has something to do with it. Just a guess. Does `@Inject Models` work? Also what are your dependencies?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha YOU SAVED MY LIFE.IT WORKED!.it was 2 days i was crawling the web for the solution